# Split files linux and then grep

Tags: unix, split, grep

I'd like to split a file and grep each piece without writing them to indvidual files.

I've attempted a couple variations of split and grep and no such luck; any suggestions?

Something along the lines of:
    split -b SIZE filename | grep "string"

I've attempted grep/fgrep to find the string but my shell complains that the files are too large. See: [use fgrep instead](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg1OA22735)

Comment: I think you need to explain your problem a bit more. Why can't you split to files and why do you need to find a pattern in each piece. Example input/output is always nice. Please update your question.

Comment: That error you linked to clearly states that some line in your file is too long, not the file itself.

Comment: completely misread that >.>; still any suggestions? fgrep gives the same error

Comment: Can you install GNU grep instead? Or Perl? `perl -ne 'print if /regex/' file`

Comment: If you are on z/OS, why is this tagged [tag:linux]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in splitting the file if you plan to [linearly] search each of the pieces anyway (assuming that's the only thing you are doing with it). Consider running `grep` on the entire file.

If however you plan to utilize the fact that the file is split later on, then the typical way would be:

- Create a temporary directory and step into it
- Run `split/csplit` on the original file
- Use `for` loop over written fragment to do your processing.

Comment: grep/fgrep results in "input lines truncated - result questionable"

Comment: That probably means that your lines are too long. What is the OS (I believe GNU grep can handle long lines)?